# Вопросы по bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, инспекция-кода

Только начал изучать сетки bootstrap(как собственно и сам bootstrap) и появилось несколько вопросов.

```css
.icons .container {
  max-width: 800px;
}

.icons img {
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.icons img {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="icons">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-4"> <img src="./img/adidas.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-4"> <img src="./img/nike.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-4"> <img src="./img/puma.png" alt=""></div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-4"> <img src="./img/asics.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-4"> <img src="./img/balance.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-4"> <img src="./img/fila.png" alt=""></div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Нормально ли прописывать классам bootstrap свои стили наподобие `.container 
   max-width: 800px;`
2. Правильно ли я делаю выравнивая изображения в колонке используя margin? Есть ли для этого специальные классы?
3. Правильно ли я делаю создавая расстояние между иконками давая им `margin40`. Можно ли писать `margin` самим колонкам?
   Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Нет, не правильно, если нужен контейнер в max 800рx пишите так:

```css
.container.custom-wrap {
        max-width: 800px
    }
```

```html
<div class="container custom-wrap">content</div>
```

2. Оберните в div и установите выравнивание по центру

```css
.image {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"><img src="..." alt=""/></div>
```

3. из пункта 2. в класс image можете просто добавить padding